# Trying to install BetterDiscord and this happens

Tags: 16.04, command-line, software-installation

So I'm on Discord and somebody was mentioning installing BetterDiscord on their Win10 PC. So I check if it can be installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer. 
I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1R2NTX-6C8
And at 6:30 in the video I copy the command:

```
sudo ./node_modules/.bin/electron ./src
```

And then I get this message in the terminal:

```
[2515:0723/031542.376647:FATAL:atom_main_delegate.cc(194)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

It was supposed to run the BetterDiscord menu, but instead it showed that.
If anybody can help solve this your time would be utmost appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the command `sudo ./node_modules/.bin/electron --no-sandbox ./src` like the error suggest.
Haven't installed discord yet on my client but could fix the problem.

Comment: That worked.. in bringing up a new error screen. There is now a blank white rectangle open titled: [Install] ,a JavaScript error, and in the terminal it says: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.